# Why are objects still created when I omit importing classes in actionscript?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm working through a tutorial to create an mp3 player in actionscript. When I delete my first 4 lines of code, the .swf still works great!  I thought you needed to declare what classes you're importing for every object you create later on.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;

//Objects and Variables
var myMusic:Sound= new Sound();
var soundFile:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("bobDylan.mp3");
var channel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();

//Listeners
btnPlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playMusic);
btnStop.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopMusic);

function stopMusic(evt:MouseEvent):void{
    channel.stop();
}

function playMusic(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    myMusic.load(soundFile);
    channel = myMusic.play();
}
```

- Why are objects still created when I omit importing classes in
  actionscript?
- Also... What other than **"classes"** can you **"import"**.  Or can
  you only import classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're working in the Flash IDE. If that is the case, then you can expect that it will be a good deal more forgiving than you would expect (or would like). Flash is probably importing the classes for you (check your publish settings and make sure they are on *strict* mode to force this issue). If it is, the objects being created are still the same objects you expect them to be, but *don't trust it, fix the code*.

The three things I've every imported are classes, functions (setTimeout, for example), and namespaces (mx_internal is used a lot in Flex).

Comment: You have to import a class, function, namespace, or the entire contents of the package. `import flash.events;` imports a package (bad), but `import flash.events.*;` imports the contents of the package.

Comment: Yeah heh, I just deleted the comment after looking at another example =)